# Closure of set of numbers whose ternary expansion have only $0,1$ in first$ $N places

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, ternary-expansion

I am trying to show that $A_N$ is closed, where $A_N \subseteq [0,1]$  is the set of real numbers whose ternary expansions have only $0$ or $1$ in the first $N$ places but can be $0,1$ or $2$ after that. I am allowed to assume that every real number in $[0, 1]$ has a ternary expansion, which is unique except for recurring $2s.$

This is what I have done so far:

Take $x \in [0,1]\setminus A_N$. Then x has at least one $2$ in the first $N$ places of its ternary expansion.

So $x= \frac{a_1}{3} + ... \frac{a_N}{3^N} + $$\sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}$$\frac{a_i}{3^i}$ where $a_i=2$ for some $i \in \{1,...,N\}$

Now suppose, for a contradiction, that $y \in (x-\frac{1}{3^i},x+\frac{1}{3^i}) \cap A_N$.

So $y=\frac{b_1}{3} + ... \frac{b_N}{3^N} + $$\sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}$$\frac{b_i}{3^i}$ where $b_i\in \{0,1\}$ for all $i \in\{1,...,N\}$

We know that $|x-y| < \frac{1}{3^i}$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here $-$ any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: $x= \frac{a_1}{3} + ... \frac{a_N}{3^N} + $$\sum_{i=N+1}^\infty $$\frac{a_i}{3^i}$, similarly for $y$.

Comment: I am not quite sure what this adds to the question @PaulFrost

Comment: Your formula for $x$ is wrong.

Comment: Oh right, thanks.

Comment: Still wrong because $x$ in general is not a finite sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

- $A_1=\left[\frac03,\frac23\right]$;
- $A_2=\left[\frac0{3^2},\frac2{3^2}\right]\cup\left[\frac3{3^2},\frac{3+2}{3^2}\right]$;
- $A_3=\left[\frac0{3^3},\frac2{3^3}\right]\cup\left[\frac3{3^3},\frac{3+2}{3^3}\right]\cup\left[\frac{3^2}{3^3},\frac{3^2+2}{3^3}\right]\cup\left[\frac{3^2+3}{3^3},\frac{3^2+3+2}{3^3}\right]$

and so on… So, each $A_N$ is a finite union of closed intervals. Therefore, it is closed.

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify how I might make this more rigorous- i.e. could I prove a formula for $A_N$?

Comment: I suppose that it is clear that $A_1$ is $\left[0,\frac23\right]$. You then get $A_2$ from $A_1$ by dividing $A_1$ into $6$ intervals all with the same length and then you take the first two intervals together (you will get $\left[\frac0{3^2},\frac2{3^2}\right]$) and the fourth and the fifth intervals together (you will get $\left[\frac3{3^2},\frac{3+2}{3^2}\right]$). And you will get $A_3$ from $A_2$ applying the same process to both intervals from $A_1$. So, $A_N$ will consist of $2^{N-1}$ closed intervals. I think that there is a closed formula for $A_N$ but I don't see now what it will be.

Comment: Let $S_n$ denote the set of ternary sums of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{3^i}$ with $a_i \ne 2$. Clearly $S_n$ is finite. In fact, it has $2^n$ elements. The set of all ternary sums $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{3^i}$ is nothing else than $[0, \frac{1}{3^n}]$. Thus $A_n = \bigcup_{x \in S_n} [x, x+\frac{1}{3^n}]$. We can rewrite this in the form $A_n = \bigcup_{x \in S_{n-1}} [x, x+\frac{1}{3^n}] \cup \bigcup_{x \in S_{n-1}} [x+\frac{1}{3^n}, x+\frac{2}{3^n}] = \bigcup_{x \in S_{n-1}} [x, x+\frac{2}{3^n}]$.